# MS build in Azure devops - where to input the version

Tags: visual-studio, azure-devops, msbuild, azure-pipelines, version

I am trying to declare the VersionAssembly and  InformationalVersion in the pipeline, this is the code:

```
  - task: MSBuild@1
    inputs:
      solution: 'My solution.sln'
      configuration: 'Release'
      msbuildArguments: '-t:build -restore /p:VersionAssembly=0.0.0.7 /p:Version=0.0.0.7 /p:VersionSuffix=0.0.0.7'
    displayName: build sln
    timeoutInMinutes: 10
```

But the ms build 'ignore' the arguments I give, and the version I put have no effect.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Are the projects in the 'My solution.sln' solution .NET SDK projects or 'old style' projects? The `AssemblyVersion`, `Version`, and `VersionSuffix` properties are recognized and supported by .NET SDK projects.

Comment: Does it work when not using the built-in `MSBuild` task, but a plain shell command like `msbuild 'My solution.sln' -t:build -restore /p:VersionAssembly=0.0.0.7 /p:Version=0.0.0.7 /p:VersionSuffix=0.0.0.7 /p:Configuration=Release`?

Answer (score 0):

You could try to use the VSbuild taks to check if it works:

```
  - task: VSBuild@1
    inputs:
      solution: 'My solution.sln'
      configuration: 'Release'
      msbuildArgs: '-t:build -restore /p:VersionAssembly=0.0.0.7 /p:Version=0.0.0.7 /p:VersionSuffix=0.0.0.7'
```

For more information, you could refer to the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/build/visual-studio-build?view=azure-devops#yaml-snippet).